# Python core libraries problem in archlinux

Tags: ros, archlinux, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings

While instaling the core libraries for ROS and following the page instructions http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Arch, I have some comments (if this is not the best place to put this, I appreciate if someone can lead me to the right place)

1. In the prerequisites part, there is no pcl package, this doesn't exist in arch official repos, only in aur, so this command should be removed.
2. The packages mantainer removed the swig-wx package that uses ROS specific implementation, and there are some issues compiling FLANN (Archlinux only related issue but is better to put it out in the open).
3. When making the core libraries, the cmake command gives error about not finding python-empy even when it's installed. This can be fixed if you force cmake to use python2 instead of python3 (or simply python in Archlinux), which I did making a simblik link to an auxiliar folder and putting it in the PATH.

   ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/alt/python

   export PATH=/usr/local/bin/alt:$PATH

This python error is because the syntax used in the command, which python3 doesn't support. Being that python3 isn't supported in ROS in general, the best solution would be to use python2 in all the process and make the user aware of this even at this stage.

Only reporting about fuerte experience so far.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32494/python-core-libraries-problem-in-archlinux/) by [Erwin Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2189/erwin-lopez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the current Arch install instructions are everything but perfect. For electric, I started wrapping all core stacks into AUR packages that should just work out of the box without any further system modifications. It's still not ready for an official release and I also want to prepare packages for Fuerte. Currently, everything can be found on [github](https://github.com/moesenle/arch-ros-stacks).

They way I fix the python3 vs python2 issue is by patching all python files to explicitly use python2, not python.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fyi, the hdf5-fortran-cxx package already in aur builds the c++ bindings.
I used it in building electric before.

---

Originally posted by [pallegro](https://answers.ros.org/users/1891/pallegro/) with karma: 36 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1